# Update site template after JSON file is updated

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, template, json-formatting

Alright I have a site using a JSON file for its template. I made changes to that JSON file to update the default view for a list. Does SharePoint update this template automatically after a timer is reached or do I need to do something manually to update it?

This is for sharepoint online.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to update this in site design --> available site designs --> re run theme on current site.